# ChartJS tooltip when having multiple lines on a time graph

Tags: chart.js

It seems that point hovering uses point index to mark up the same point on multiple data sets. So when I hover over index 1 on one data set, the index 1 is also styled with hovering on any other data set, even though it is not the same date at all.

How can I make it ONLY show tool tip for the actual point hovered? Or at least NOT mark up points that are not the same date as the hovered one?

https://codepen.io/texton/pen/RwWdEwY

[image]

Here are the options.scales:

```
  scales: {
     xAxes: [
          {
            ticks: {
            autoSkip: true,
                        maxTicksLimit: 20
                    },
                    bounds: 'data',
                    type: 'time',
                    distribution: 'linear',
                    time: {
                        tooltipFormat: 'ddd DD. MMMM',
                        unit: 'week',
                        displayFormats: {
                            week: 'WW'
                        }
                    },
                    gridLines: {
                        display: false
                    }
                }
            ],
            yAxes: [
                {
                    id: 'weight',
                    type: 'linear',
                    position: 'left',
                    ticks: {
                        callback(value) {
                            return value + 'kg';
                        }
                    },
                    gridLines: {
                        display: false
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define the hover mode, like this:

```
options: {
  hover: {
    mode: 'nearest'
  }
}
```

Here is your [example](https://codepen.io/jebenja/pen/KKVEwNe), with the correct hover mode:

Answer (score 0):

You could explicitly define the [`tooltips.mode`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/interactions/modes.html#interaction-modes) inside the chart options, `'nearest'` would be a good choice.

```
options: {
  tooltips: {
    mode: 'nearest'
  }
```

> [`nearest`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/interactions/modes.html#nearest): Gets the items that are at the nearest distance to the point.

I'm wondering however why it doesn't already work as expected because according to [Tooltip Configuration](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#tooltip-configuration), `mode: 'nearest'` is actually the default. It could be that this wasn't the case in older versions of Chart.js. Therefore make sure to use the most recent stable version of the library (currently [v2.9.3](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/releases/tag/v2.9.3)).